# Deriving the shape of the suspension bridge

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to determine the shape of the cable of a suspension bridge, where it is assumed that the total weight of the load, the cable and the roadway per horizontal distance is constant.

In my attempt, I first considered an infinitesimal element $dx$. Assuming the element is stationary, all the forces affecting it must add up to zero (Newton's second law). Thus we get the following expressions for the vertical and horizontal forces

$\begin{cases} T_1sin(\theta+d\theta)=T_2sin(\theta)+W \\ T_1cos(\theta+d\theta)=T_2cos(\theta) \end{cases} \tag{1}\label{1}$

where $T_1$ is the tension force pulling $dx$ upwards and to the right, $T_2$ is the tension force pulling $dx$ downwards and to the left. $W$ is the load that $dx$ experiences and can also be rewritten as $W=\rho dx$ ($\rho$ is the load per horizontal distance). The diagram of the forces is shown below.

Combining the equations from $\eqref{1}$, I get

$$ tan(\theta+d\theta)=tan(\theta)+\frac{W}{T_2cos(\theta)}, \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$ \frac{tan(\theta+d\theta)-tan(\theta)}{d\theta}=\frac{W}{T_2cos(\theta)d\theta}. \tag{3}\label{3}$$

At this point, I'm using the definition of the derivative to rewrite $\eqref{3}$ as

$$ \frac{d}{d\theta}tan(\theta)=\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\rho}{T_2cos(\theta)} \frac{dx}{d\theta}, $$
$$ sec^2(\theta) = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\rho}{T_2cos(\theta)} \frac{dx}{d\theta}, $$

but this doesn't get me anywhere. I then try a different tactic and rewrite $\eqref{2}$ as

$$ y'(x+dx)-y'(x)=\frac{W}{T_2cos(\theta)}, $$
$$ \frac{y'(x+dx)-y'(x)}{dx}=\frac{\rho dx}{T_2cos(\theta)dx}, $$
$$ y''(x)=\frac{\rho}{T_2cos(\theta)}. \tag{4}\label{4}$$

I cannot integrate $\eqref{4}$ as there is an unclear dependence between $\theta$ and $x$. Alas, I'm stuck.

How can I get the shape of $y(x)$ using the method I outlined? I know that it's possible to take a special case $\theta=0$ (the vertex of the parabola) and the answer is immediate. But I would like to see a derivation for an arbitrary point $x$, not involving the vertex.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the only thing that was missing from my analysis was an additional relation between $T_1$ and $T_2$. Since $T_1$ differs from $T_2$ in magnitude and direction, we can express this difference using an element $\Delta T$. Then, $T_2=T$ and $T=T+\Delta T$. Using this notation I then rewrite Equations (1) in the following way:

$$ \begin{cases} (T+\Delta T)sin(\theta+d\theta)=Tsin(\theta)+W \\ (T+\Delta T)cos(\theta+d\theta)=Tcos(\theta) \end{cases} ​$$

I then expand both of these equations, divide them by $\Delta x$, and find the limit of both sides as $\Delta x \to 0$.

From the first expression I get

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(Tcos(\theta))=0, $$

which means that the horizontal component of the tensile force is always constant. We can denote it as $T_H=Tcos(\theta)=const.$

From the second expression I get

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(Tsin(\theta))=\rho. $$

Integrating this we get

$$ Tsin(\theta)=\int \rho \,dx .\tag{1}\label{1}$$

Dividing $\eqref{1}$ by $T_H$ we get

$$ tan(\theta)=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{T_H} \int \rho \,dx. $$

A second integration then yields

$$ y=\frac{1}{T_H} \int \left (\int \rho \,dx \right ) \,dx. $$

This is an equation of the parabola.

References:
[Expressing Derivative of Cable Tension Component](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246026/expressing-derivative-of-cable-tension-component?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

Two variable tensions in the cable are not suitable to fix up a differential equation /relation because we need to compute many steps at many points.

***Only one variable cable tension $T$*** should be involved, along with an external variable cable self weight $W$ .

The triangle of forces including **three** forces should be drawn. I have used same length color and direction for representing force vectors. Horizontal force inside the cable $H$ is unknown at present.

$$ \tan \theta = \frac{W}{H}= \frac{\rho x}{ H}= \frac{dy}{dx} $$

Integrate with BC at bottom of parabola shape cable $ (x=0,y=0) $

$$ y = \frac{\rho x^2}{2H}; $$

[image]

Comment: Here you're applying the fact that $\theta=0$ at the vertex of the parabola (following my analysis). I explicitly mentioned in my question that this solution is known to me, but I would like to obtain it for any arbitrary point, where $H$ as per your diagram is not necessarily horizontal. Is that possible?

Comment: At the last step after integration is over then only it is realized that it is a parabola. Then after applying boundary conditions at lowest point the above result is obtained. I am not applying θ=0 at vertex because the vertex lowest point is simply not yet available!                                       $H$ is horizontal force *by definition/assumption*.

Comment: The horizontal force H is necessarily located at the lowest point of the curve - the vertex of the parabola. I can easily arrive at the same answer you derived by setting $\theta=0$ in my analysis. But that's not what I want. I want to know how to get the shape of the curve, which you've shown to be parabolic, by considering an arbitrary point that is not located at the trough, i.e. where H is not horizontal. Exactly as shown in my diagram. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: By equilibrium of horizontal forces $ T_2 \cos \theta = H $= constant as in your derivation Equation (4). There is no other force.  So, tension upwards  $   T_2\text{ changes always and }= H \sec \theta.  $

Comment: As far as I see, $|T_1|=|T_2|=const$, but the horizontal component $T_2cos(\theta)\neq const$ because the angle $\theta$ varies from point to point.

Comment: $|T_1|=|T_2|=$ const  is *not* correct in the present case. It varies from point to point as well as between ends of an infinitesimal cable differential length of arc.